# Unable to modify value in _init_ function

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a Button class in python and I want to give a unique number to each button because when I will draw multiple buttons on pygame window, I will need to differentiate between these buttons using those unique numbers.
The problem is I'm unable to modify the unique number (unq_number += 1 [Line 10 in code]).
Python is giving me this error [local variable 'unq_number' referenced before assignment]
but I have already defined the variable in the code (Line 4 in code).

```
import pygame

class Button:
    unq_number = 0

    def __init__(self, text, bg_color, width, height, pos, gui_font):
        self.pressed = False

        # unique number for each button
        unq_number += 1
        self.unq_number = unq_number

        # Rectangle
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
        self.bg_color = bg_color

        # text
        self.text_surf = gui_font.render(text, True, '#FFFFFF')
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def draw(self, surface, txt_color):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.bg_color, self.rect)
        surface.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        return self.check_click(txt_color)

    def check_click(self, txt_color):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.bg_color = (0, 125, 110)

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.pressed = True
            else:
                if self.pressed == True:
                    self.pressed = False
                    return self.unq_number
        else:
            self.bg_color = txt_color
```

Comment: write self before *unq_number* like this : ```self.unq_number += 1```

Comment: define `unq_number` outside class. if you define it inside the class, you have to reference it via `self`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must distinguish between the class attribute (see [Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)) and the instance attribute (see [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)). The class attribute is addressed with `Button.unq_number` and the instance attribute with `self.unq_number`.

minimal example

```py
class Button:
    unq_number = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Button.unq_number += 1
        self.unq_number = Button.unq_number

bl = []
for _ in range(4):
    bl.append(Button())
    print(f"{Button.unq_number} buttons: {[b.unq_number for b in bl]}")
```

output

> ```
> 1 buttons: [1]
> 2 buttons: [1, 2]
> 3 buttons: [1, 2, 3]
> 4 buttons: [1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

*self reference to **this** class here and you need to write **self** before your variable*

```
import pygame

class Button:
    unq_number = 0

    def __init__(self, text, bg_color, width, height, pos, gui_font):
        self.pressed = False

        # unique number for each button
        self.unq_number += 1
        #self.unq_number = unq_number

        # Rectangle
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos, (width, height))
        self.bg_color = bg_color

        # text
        self.text_surf = gui_font.render(text, True, '#FFFFFF')
        self.text_rect = self.text_surf.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def draw(self, surface, txt_color):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.bg_color, self.rect)
        surface.blit(self.text_surf, self.text_rect)
        return self.check_click(txt_color)

    def check_click(self, txt_color):
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.bg_color = (0, 125, 110)

            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
                self.pressed = True
            else:
                if self.pressed == True:
                    self.pressed = False
                    return self.unq_number
        else:
            self.bg_color = txt_color
```

Comment: there is also no point in returning the variable that is inside the constructor